# How to reliably identify a Throttling ServiceException in C# GraphSDK

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am currently testing ways to reliably detect throttling in the C# GraphSdk.

When sending too many contact requests (10.000req/10min) to:

```
/v1.0/users/{Userid}/contacts/{contactId}
```

I will receive the following ServiceException:

[image]

My first idea was to just check against the StatusCode, but since it is from type  [System.Net.HttpStatusCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx) the "Throttling" code 429 sent by the REST API is not contained in the enum.

Currently I use this code to detect a throttling message:

```
if(e.StatusCode.ToString() == "429")
{
    Console.WriteLine("this is an throttling exception");
}
```

The disadvantage of this approach is, that if in some time in the future an enum for 429 is added this code will fail. Silently. Resulting in a hard to notice bug.

I can't use, the string-property `Code` from the `Error-PropertyObj`, as it is not guaranteed to be always the same Message e.g. "Too Many Requests".
Especially in this case the `ErrorCode` (string) is set wrongly to "unknown error"  instead of "Too many Requests" (probably a bug).

- Any recommendations or ideas how I could reliably notice a Throttling
  error?
- Especially recommendations on how to reliably compare if the
  HTTPStatusCode equals 429?
- Maybe there is some documentation describing another way to check for the error code?

Comment: If of interest I used a simple for-loop over 
    "var result = await graphClient.Users[userId].Contacts[contactId].Request().GetAsync();"
send by multiple clients under the same tenant, to produce my Throttling case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid being hit by any changes to the `HttpStatusCode` enumeration by using the `int` rather than the `string` value. As you noted, the `string` would change if an enum was added for `429` but the `int` value will remain the same:

```
switch ((int) e.StatusCode)
{
    case 429:
        Console.WriteLine("this is an throttling exception");
        break;

    default:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to look at the response headers.  When we 429 you, we add a Retry-After response header which you can actually see in your screen shot above.

Comment: Please note that the Retry-After response header is not always present for 429 responses from Microsoft Graph.